# Select query output while other user is inserting record on same table

Tags: sql

What will be the output of select query if at the same time other is inserting data in the same table?

Comment: That really depends on what **concrete RDBMS** you're using - not all of them handle this the same way .....

Answer (score 1):

For DBMS properly implementing the ACID principle, the result for a select statement does not change during its execution. Logically you can picture that as the database taking a snapshot of all the data the moment your query starts and only retrieves the data from that snapshot (of course: physically this is **not** done by copying that data prior to running a query).

The most common implementation of this "snapshot" taking is called [Multi Version Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). The name indicates what happens in the background: for each row the database keeps multiple versions around that are valid for the transactions reading that data.

The above assumes that the transactions use at least the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level. If the current transaction uses the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level (allowing dirty reads) then the above would not be true.

Answer (score 0):

the select will only show what was committed to the database. If the user is editing, but has not committed, it will show whatever was already there. If the data was committed before the select actually happened, you would see the new values.

Comment: If auto commit is on ..? I mean how auto commit works .. after insertion of total records or after each row insertion..?